# How can I find out if an data- attribute is set to an empty value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to find out if an data- attribute is set to an empty value or if the value of it is not set at all?

See this fiddle example (Check the console when clicking on the elements):

http://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/yy8qvwfp/

```
<div onclick="console.log($(this).attr('data-test'))">undefined</div>

<div data-test="" onclick="console.log($(this).attr('data-test'))">empty</div>

<!-- this one will also return an empty value -->
<div data-test onclick="console.log($(this).attr('data-test'))">null</div>

<div data-test="value" onclick="console.log($(this).attr('data-test'))">value</div>
```

Im having the issue with the third example. I need to know if the attribute actually is set to an empty value or if it is not set at all. Is that actually possible?

**EDIT:** The reason I'm asking is that I'm updating content with the attributes value, so `data-test=""` should update the content to an empty value, but `data-test` should do nothing at all

Comment: Are you trying to find out *if*, or *whether*?

Comment: How does empty and null difference in context? is it something crucial or you are just trying to understand better?

Comment: Im updating content with the attribute, so data-test="" should update the content to an empty value, but data-test should do nothing at all

Comment: I've seen others that have had a similar issue. I don't remember if there's a resolution or not, but a rather ugly solution would be to get the `.outerHTML` of the element and parse the opening tag so you can manually check. You'd only have to do that if you're getting the empty string. I'll try to think if there's another way, but I'm a little doubtful.

Comment: @cookiemonster I was literally just going to suggest that (not even sure if it works though). I think that's the *only* solution, unfortunately a dirty one. I've looked into `.dataset`, `.getAttribute()`, `.attributes` and they don't help

Comment: @Ian: Now that I think of it, the `.outerHTML` will probably give the same output either way, since it doesn't reflect the original source, but rather a dynamic serialization.

Comment: @cookiemonster Agreed, just tested and that's true. The newly posted answer seems correct

Comment: @StephanWagner: *"Is there a way to find out if an data- attribute is set to an empty value or if it is not set at all?"* Not set **at all** would be not having `data-test` in the tag **at all**: `<div onclick="console.log($(this).attr('data-test'))">completely missing</div>` If you have `data-test` in the tag but you don't give it a value, its value is `""`. E.g., `<div data-test></div>` and `<div data-test=""></div>` are **exactly** the same thing (with `data-*` attributes).

Comment: FYI, if you change the back end to entirely remove the attribute as a substitute for the "no value" version, then you can use `this.hasAttribute("data-test")` to see if it exists. Or if you must use jQuery, then `$(this).is("[data-test]")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible. The two following elements are normalized to the same thing (the first).

```
<div data-test="" onclick="console.log($(this).attr('data-test'))">empty</div>

<!-- this one will also return an empty value -->
<div data-test onclick="console.log($(this).attr('data-test'))">null</div>
```

I tested this by checking the `outerHTML` of both elements. You're going to need to come up with a different way to achieve this.

Comment: Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0 (item “Empty attribute syntax”). This applies to HTML5 in HTML syntax. In XHTML syntax, an attribute name without an equals sign and a quoted value is not permitted at all (it is a well-formedness violation).

Comment: All right, thanks for that, I'll see if I can come up with a different solution then